# What went wrong on 200-point SRM on TopCoder?

Tags: c++, algorithm

When I submitted the code on TopCoder, it only gave me 60 points on a 200 points SRM.
I think there is something wrong with the algorithm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
    public:
    string whatTime(int seconds)
    {
        int hours=0, minutes=0, secs=0;
        ostringstream cHours, cMinutes, cSeconds;
        string sHours, sMinutes, sSeconds;
        string theReturns;

        while (seconds > 0)
        {
            if (seconds > 3600)
            {
                hours++;
                seconds -= 3600;
            }
            else if (seconds > 60)
            {
                minutes++;
                seconds -= 60;
            } else {
                secs ++;
                seconds--;
            }
        }

        cHours << hours;
        cMinutes << minutes;
        cSeconds << secs;

        sHours = cHours.str() + ":";
        sMinutes = cMinutes.str() + ":";
        sSeconds = cSeconds.str();

        theReturns = sHours + sMinutes + sSeconds;

        return (theReturns);
    }
};  

/* Main Function for Me, I didn't submitted it on TopCoder, they only want the class */ 
int main()
{
    Time myTime;
    cout << myTime.whatTime(3661);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: instead of giving me negative votes, help me, I don't think any of you who gave the negative votes, became good without help, what do you think if people instead of helping gave you hard time?!

Comment: What makes you think the people who downvoted this are any good? You just insulted me sir!

Comment: SO is not a good "code review" site. Please ask a focused question (i.e. about a specific identified/isolated issue). Also, this is solvable *without* loops much more cleanly.

Comment: i don't know whats wrong, how should i ask a specific identified question?!

Comment: You may be getting down votes because this is not a code review site.  You'll want to go to http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MichaelScavo We don't know "what's wrong" either! Although I would suggest updating the algorithm to the standard *division and modulus* approach. In addition, what happens when a component is only *one* digits? `1:2:3` would be funny output.

Comment: Also, you didn't post the requirements that your class or program is to solve.  Don't post a link, but paste in the requirements.

Comment: How is your solution marked?

Comment: If it is based upon efficiency of the code, code size etc then there is a lot you can do to improve the code.  For example you can probably remove the loop.  You can probably also remove the use of ostringstream if you want it to be fast.  or at least only use 1 ostringstream

Comment: @MichaelScavo On TopCoder, points are awarded based on how long it takes you to solve; i.e. it starts off at 200 and the question drops in value the longer it takes for you to solve the problem. If you got any points at all, that means your program *worked*. The reason why it'd only be 60 is because you took a while (you'll get more points the faster you solve)

Comment: @DennisMeng hit the nail on the head. Regarding whether your question is appropriate: I have no problems with it at all, except for the fact that you didn't say what the TopCoder question *actually was*.  People are huffing and puffing that SO is not a code review site, but there's really no clear line.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Code Review is not a "fix the bug in my code" site. The way this question was currently written, I understand why it is downvoted here (the same question would likely have got downvoted on CR as well). However, once [the question reached Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36359/a-bug-in-my-code-for-a-topcoder-srm-problem) it was a much better fit for StackOverflow than Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reduce the number of `ostringstream` to one.  Use the stream insertion operator on the one stream.

Also, use math statements instead of "if" statements:

```
hours = seconds / 3600;
seconds_remaining = seconds % 3600;
```

The math statements will eliminate the need for a loop.